# Showing sidebar-2 on custom template page

Tags: page-template, sidebar, register-sidebar

Environment: WP 3.5, Twenty Twelve child theme. I created a custom template.
Now, I'd like to display the built-in sidebar-2 in this custom template page (instead of the default sidebar-1).
sidebar-2 is already registered by twenty twelve functions.php.
I read a bit about get_sidebar and how to activate other sidebars, but I'm still a bit confused.
To activate sidebar-2 on this custom template I created a file sidebar-customtemplate.php in my child theme directory with this content:

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-2' ) ) : ?>
    <div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">               
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-2' ); ?>
    </div><!-- #secondary -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Then in my custom template file I replaced `get_sidebar();` with `<?php get_sidebar( $customtemplate ); ?>`. Then I added some widgets to the sidebar-2 (from Appearance - Widget), but in the home page still sidebar-1 is displayed! Why? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php get_sidebar( 'customtemplate' ); ?>
```

did the thing :)

Answer (score 0):

you can put this code in your functions

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
function register_my_menus() {
    register_nav_menus(
        array(
            'menu-1' => __( 'Head' )
        )
    );
}
```

and this code, in the place you want your second menu

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'menu-1' ) ); ?>
```

and than, you can control your new menu, through the [menu section](http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide) in the admin panel

Comment: Uhm, no. I don't need to register a menu. I need to use the already registered by default (in twenty twelve) "sidebar-2" in a custom template page.

Comment: Oh, sorry, i didnt noticed. did you check if its passing the if condition?

Answer (score 0):

Rename that sidebar-2 into sidebar-sidebar2.php and after use this code

```
<?php get_sidebar('sidebar2');?>
```

hope its may work

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a CSS that includes both left and right side bars?

```
/*----------------------------------------------------
    2 sidebars
---------------------------------------------------- */
#sidebar {
    Float:left;
    width:20%;
    display:block;
}
#sidebar-core {
    margin-right:20px;
}
#main {
    float: left;
    width: 65%;
    display: block;
}
#intro,
#main-core {
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
#sidebarright {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 15%;
}
#sidebarright-core {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Upload this in your styles in your theme. Name it something like two-sidebars.css,
then go to your functions.php and require this once. You will have to define the path, an example is like this:

```
wp_register_style( 'twosidebars', get_template_directory_uri() . '/styles/layouts/two-sidebar.css', '', '1.1' );
```

You will see the other sidebar options for requirements. Model what you do off that.

Now you will need a new sidebar.php that calls the CSS, so create a new one and name it something like sidbar2.php and insert something like this:

```
<div id="sidebar">
        <div id="sidebar-core">    
            <?php do_action( 'before_sidebar' ); ?>
            <?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar() get_sidebar() ); ?>   
        </div>
</div><!-- #sidebar -->

<div id="sidebarright">
        <div id="sidebarright-core">
            <?php do_action( 'before_sidebar' ); ?>
            <?php if ( ! dynamic_sidebar() get_sidebar(sidebar2) ); ?>   
        </div>
</div><!-- #sidebar2 -->
```

Now all of this assumes you have already registered the array sidebar2 as an array in your functions.php. This also assumes you edited your stylesheet to include a separate style for sidebar2.